# Does Vaadin have the equivalent of a JavaFX GridPane?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, vaadin, gridpane

In JavaFX, multiple UI elements can be displayed to the user in a grid, using a [`GridPane`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html). Vaadin has a [grid layout](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-grid), however their [`Grid`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.5.2/com/vaadin/flow/component/grid/Grid.html) doesn't function as a container for other elements. Instead, it appears to be used as a table for displaying individual beans as rows. Vaadin does have an [ordered layout](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-ordered-layout/), however, I don't think it can be used to create a grid of other UI elements.

How would I replicate the behavior of JavaFX's GridPane in Vaadin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Vaadin 8 there was a [GridLayout](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/layout/layout-gridlayout) available, that resembles a GridPane. There is no exact replacement in Vaadin Flow, but there is a third party compoenent [CssGridLayout](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/css-grid-layout) that may fit the bill.